# NUnit : How to prevent calling base class constructor or mocking base class constructor (ASP.NET MVC controller method testing with NUnit)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nunit

I am testing an ASP.NET MVC application with NUnit (on the .NET framework).

I am trying to test `SomeController` method which is inheriting from `BaseController`.

In `BaseController`, there is a parameterless constructor which read configuration, open db connection, writing logs etc.

When I do unit testing of one of method in `SomeController`, it keeps calling `BaseController`'s constructor.

I wanted to mock `BaseController` so that its constructor is not getting called.

I tried mocking `BaseController` but not sure how the same used with `SomeController` as mocked base class.

How to resolve this? Waiting for answers and alternate approach ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Design Patterns](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/dp) recommend,

> Favor object composition over class inheritance.

You are running into one of several problems with inheritance, as it's implemented in mainstream languages like C#. AFAIK, there's no direct resolution to that problem.

Either change the base class so that its constructor doesn't do all of that implicit work ([constructors should be simple](https://vuscode.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection/)), or don't inherit from `BaseController`.

In the latter case, favour Constructor Injection instead of inheriting from a base class.

```
public sealed class SomeController
{
    private readonly ISomeDependency dep;

    public SomeController(ISomeDependency dep)
    {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    // Use this.dep in methods...
}
```

This should enable you to test `SomeController` by supplying a [Test Double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) of the dependency.

Comment: Thanks mark.

I am working on a legacy application.

Working on the solution as suggested by you. Before that need to figure out changes in existing code.